# is this a result of firestore latency or normal behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a form I am using to allow users to add comments to my site. The form has an input field, a textarea field, and a button. When the button is clicked it runs my addComment() function which adds the name, comment, and timestamp to my firestore collection as a new doc.

It seems like after I click the button to add a comment I have to wait a few seconds before I can post another one. If I try to add a new comment too quickly then request doesn't get sent to my firestore collection, but if I wait a few seconds everything works as expected.

I am curious if this is normal behavior? How can I set it up so users can always post comments without having to wait a few seconds? Can someone explain to me what is happening?

Thanks
Update:
I have been doing some debugging, and I have noticed that both of the functions getVisitorCount() and getUserComments() from the first useEffect run every time I type something into the name or comment input boxes. I have attached screenshots to showcase what is happening.

On the first initial load of the app:
[image]

After typing something in the name input box:
[image]

Finally, typing something into the comment box as well:
[image]

This is not the desired behavior I want these two functions should not be running when I am typing something into either text field. The getUserComments function should only run on the initial render of the app, and whenever the add comment button is clicked.
Could this be what is causing the problems I am experiencing?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavBar, Footer, Home, About } from "./imports";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { db } from "./firebase-config";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  doc,
  updateDoc,
  addDoc,
  Timestamp,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormdata] = useState([]);
  const [numberOfVisitors, setnumberOfVistors] = useState([]);
  const [userComments, setUserComments] = useState([]);

  const portfolioStatsRef = collection(db, "portfolio-stats");
  const userCommentsRef = collection(db, "user-comments");

  const currentNumberOfVisitors = numberOfVisitors.map((visitors) => {
    return (
      <h2 className="p-3 mb-0 bg-dark bg-gradient text-white" key={visitors.id}>
        Number of vistors: {visitors.visitor_count}
      </h2>
    );
  });

  const listOfUserComments = userComments.map((comment) => {
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={comment.id}>
        <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-center">
          <h5 className="mb-1">{comment.name}</h5>
          <small>{comment.date.toDate().toString()}</small>
        </div>
        <p className="d-flex justify-content-center mb-1">{comment.comment}</p>
      </li>
    );
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getVisitorCount = async () => {
      const dataFromPortfolioStatsCollection = await getDocs(portfolioStatsRef);

      setnumberOfVistors(
        dataFromPortfolioStatsCollection.docs.map((doc) => {
          return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
        })
      );
    };

    const getUserComments = async () => {
      const dataFromUserCommentsCollection = await getDocs(userCommentsRef);

      setUserComments(
        dataFromUserCommentsCollection.docs.map((doc) => {
          return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
        })
      );
    };
    getVisitorCount();
    getUserComments();
  }, [numberOfVisitors, portfolioStatsRef, userCommentsRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateVisitorCount = async () => {
      const portfolioStatsDoc = doc(
        db,
        "portfolio-stats",
        numberOfVisitors[0].id
      );
      const updatedFields = {
        visitor_count: numberOfVisitors[0].visitor_count + 1,
      };
      await updateDoc(portfolioStatsDoc, updatedFields);
    };

    if (!numberOfVisitors.length) return;

    let sessionKey = sessionStorage.getItem("sessionKey");

    if (sessionKey === null) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("sessionKey", "randomString");
      updateVisitorCount();
    }
  }, [numberOfVisitors]);

  const handleFormData = (event) => {
    setFormdata((prevFormData) => {
      return {
        ...prevFormData,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      };
    });
  };

  const addComment = async () => {
    const newComment = {
      name: formData.name,
      comment: formData.comment,
      date: Timestamp.now(),
    };
    await addDoc(userCommentsRef, newComment);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="d-flex flex-column overflow-hidden min-vh-100 vh-100">
        <NavBar />
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col text-center">
            {numberOfVisitors.length === 0 && (
              <h2 className="p-3 mb-0 bg-dark bg-gradient text-danger">
                Sorry, the Firestore free tier quota has been met for today.
                Please come back tomorrow to see portfilio stats.
              </h2>
            )}
            {currentNumberOfVisitors}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-image">
          <div className="postion-relative">
            <main className="flex-grow-1">
              <div className="container-fluid p-0">
                <Router>
                  <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                  </Routes>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="center-items col">
                      <h4 className="">Comments</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="center-items col">
                      <div className="comments-container">
                        {userComments.length === 0 && (
                          <h4 className="text-danger bg-dark m-1 p-1">
                            Sorry, the Firestore free tier quota has been met
                            for today. Please come back tomorrow to see
                            portfilio comments.
                          </h4>
                        )}
                        {listOfUserComments}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="center-items col">
                      <h4 className="text-dark">Leave a comment</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="center-items col">
                      <form className="comment-form">
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            className="bg-transparent form-control"
                            id="floatingInput"
                            name="name"
                            onChange={handleFormData}
                          />
                          <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-floating">
                          <textarea
                            className="form-textarea-field bg-transparent form-control mb-1"
                            name="comment"
                            id="floatingTextarea"
                            onChange={handleFormData}
                          />
                          <label htmlFor="floatingTextarea">Comment</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="d-grid">
                          <button
                            className="btn btn-primary mb-4"
                            onClick={() => addComment()}
                          >
                            Add Comment
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Router>
              </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It would help if you made more concrete observations about what this code does, for example, by stepping through the code in a debugger and explaining what you see, or logging information at time when you think something should happen and checking the results.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for the suggestion. I have already tested the code with a console.log statement just to make sure the click event is being triggered on every click, and it is working as intended. However, the only other code in that function is to add the new commment information to my firestore db. I am unsure of how to test if this is just firestore's normal behavior or if there is something wrong with my code. I know I am getting all of the correct values, but its just that firestore isn't adding the new comment if I don't wait in betweeen button clicks

Comment: It would help if you show all that logging, both code and output, with timestamps, so we can see what you see.  There is nothing naturally slow about Firestore, so let's entertain the idea that you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated the question with new details & screenshots. Please take a look thanks

Comment: There's still no timing information here.  We can't see from what you've shown how long anything actually takes.  Your code also does not show the logging you added.  What we really need to see is logging with timestamps that shows exactly how long each operation is taking, and match that back to lines of code we can see.

Comment: Also it seems you are now layer in a description of a completely new problem other than timing.  That's just too much for one question.  A question should only deal with one issue at a time.

Comment: @DougStevenson I agree lets focus on one problem at a time. I commented out all of my useEffects, and just focused on the button click function itself. I just wanted to see if the new comments were being added to the firestore db. I discovered that even with all of the useEffects commented out the comments were not being added to the db if I clicked the "add comment" button too quickly. So I decided too do more research about firestore usage limits. I discovered that firestore limits writes to one per second. So by clicking too fast I may be reaching the limit which would explain this behavior

Comment: @DougStevenson The relevant documentation can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)

Comment: @DougStevenson I figured out the problem I had to use preventDefault so that my form wouldn't refresh the page before the comment could be added to the db. Thank you for all your help.